# File handling in C: Strip spaces at the beginning and end of text file

Tags: c, formatting, file-handling

The following is a function that reads a file user.dat (attached after the code) and extracts a string and an int value delimited by ", " and "\n" respectively.

```
void getUsers()
{
     int i, t;
     char *token1, *u;
     FILE *fu = fopen("user.dat", "r");
     const char s[2] = ", ";
     if(fu != NULL)
     {
        char line1[20];
         while(fgets(line1, sizeof line1, fu) != NULL)
         {
             token1 = strtok(line1, s);
             for(i=0;i<2;i++)
             {
                 if(i==0)
                 {  
                     u = token1;
                     token1 = strtok(NULL,s);
                 } else {
                     t=atoi(token1);
                 }      
             }
             addOuterNode(u,t);
         }
         printOuterNode();
         fclose(fu);
     } else {
         perror("user.dat");
     }
}
```

The user.dat file is as follows:

```
1000, 76
0095, 81
2910, 178
0001, 1
<EOF>
```

The program works fine if the above format is maintained.

However I run into problems (SIGSEGV generally as the *u and t values are sent to a function that inserts them into void * data elements in nodes of a linked list/nested linked list) when there are stray spaces or newlines in the file. Eg:

```
<newline>
1000, 76
 <space>
0095, 81
2910, 178
0001, 1
 <space><newline>
<newline>
<EOF>
```

Would you be able to help me to preprocess the user.dat textfile so that I can remove the unwanted whitespace characters?

Comment: check : Is token  `""` (or NULL).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY With an if-else statement or istoken() a predefined function?

Comment: In your favorite way

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess a file to exclude lines containing only whitespace characters. E.g. in Perl this would be:
    perl -ne "print if !/^\s*$/" input.txt > output.txt

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. But unfortunately I'll have to do it in C.